# URGENT HELP Account Suspended This Account has been suspended

Tags: hosting

Please help,

I cannot log into our database as there is an error message saying Account Suspended please contact your Hosting Provider for more information.

Does anyone know how to get around this or where to find help as we really need to log onto our database.

Thanks,

Grace

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some more information. Are you able to access CiviCRM at all?  Can you log in to your CMS (e.g. Drupal, Joomla, WordPress)?  Is CiviCRM linked to your website?  Is your website working?

Comment: Are you happy to share a link to your CiviCRM site?  This could help to diagnose the problem but please be aware that this is a public forum so don't post anything that you aren't happy to share publicly.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like an issue with your hosting provider rather than a problem with CiviCRM.  I would suggest that you get in touch with your hosting provider as the error message says.

If you don't know who your hosting provider is, I would suggest that you contact the person who set up CiviCRM for you.